# React leaflet Markers did not appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I created a react FC and calling a rest service in the "useEffect" which should receive an array of MapPoints.
For each of those mappoints i want to create a "Marker", but it doesn't work..
If I add a "static" list of mappoints, it works..

MapComponent:

```
return isLoading 
      ? <h1>Data are loading...</h1>
      : 
      <MapContainer center={[47.217324, 13.097555]} zoom={5} scrollWheelZoom={false}>

         <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" 
        />
        
        <MapMarkers mapPoints={data}/>
        
    </MapContainer>
```

MapMarkersComponent:

```
 export const MapMarkers : React.FC<Props> = ({mapPoints}) => {


    const markers = mapPoints.map((x, index) => {
        console.log(x);
        <Marker key={index} position={{lat: x.Latitude, lng: x.Longitude}}>
            <Popup>
                <span>test</span>
            </Popup>
        </Marker>
    })
    return <Fragment>{markers}</Fragment>
    
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: `markers` variable should be inside `{}` between the `Fragment` as a start

Comment: sorry yes.. copy paste mistake...

Comment: Works for me. In the beginning you have an empty array then you make an api call and populate your array of markers with coordinates and they don't show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where your mistake lies but I can provide an example for you to see it's working

In the map comp:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q=paris&type=street")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log(response);
        setData(response.features);
      });
  }, []);

  ... rest of the code as yours
```

and in the markers comp exactly the same as yours only I changed the position values cause it is different from your api and also add a **return** inside markers function where you are mapping the markers

```
const MapMarkers = ({ mapPoints }) => {
      const markers = mapPoints.map((x, index) => {
        // console.log(x);
        const {
          geometry: { coordinates }
        } = x;
        return (
          <Marker
            key={index}
            position={{ lat: coordinates[1], lng: coordinates[0] }}
            icon={icon}
          >
            <Popup>
              <span>test</span>
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        );
      });
    
      return markers;
    };
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v3x-markers-dont-not-appear-zpet1)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue..
I am using typescript and I had an issue in the MapPoint object..
So the x.Latitude was not recognized..